# How can I do a DOM action at a specific frame in a 3s video?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, video

I need to make a succession of images consisting of 25 frames run on page load. Each frame is shown for 150ms. On the 20th frame I would like an html element (a countdown timer) to appear at a specific place on the video a (white box)..I would like to run this video at a 100% viewport width as soon as the page loads.

The way I see it so far there are a few options:

1. Encoding the images into a video and hosting this on vimeo. I assume the limitation will be that the video takes different times to load on different browsers. So maybe I could watch a specific pixel at a defined ratio on the screen (for mobile etc) and when this turns white I display the countdown (is this even possible?). The positives are that the playback will always be smooth.
2. I load each image programatically with javascript and some basic setTimeout logic. The problem with this is I think the way the event loop works means setTimeout isnt that reliable. And the images dont play smoothly especially on first load. Im really seeing them glitch past the whole animation on reload of page with caching turned off. I've put all 25 images in a `display:none` div at the top of the page in the hope that they will preload but no luck. It still glitches.
3. Is there a better way? Maybe Greensock? I'm really unsure how I should approach this. I need the images to preload, but be hidden, then the javascript logic to run the 25 frames SMOOTHLY at 150ms each without glitching. And to be able to insert a dom element at exactly 20 frames in.

Any advice or any other suggestions would be super appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a marker to your video using the [videojs-markers](http://sampingchuang.com/videojs-markers) library.  It contains a callback method `onMarkerReached` which you could use to initiate your countdown.

Your code would look something like this:

```
<video id="demo" controls class="video-js vjs-default-skin">
   <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

```
var player = videojs('demo');
player.markers({
    markers: [
       {time: 3, text: ""}
    ],
    onMarkerReached: function(marker) {
        // start your timer
    },
});
```

Comment: im getting Uncaught TypeError: player.markers is not a function at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> .. i only have access to frontend of the site, so have to import all the stuff and videojs-markers.min.js is having a cross origin problem.. is this the issue?

Comment: lol im using mutation observer to read the current-time div from the control bar now

Comment: @alecbaldwin Did you include the dependencies?  You'll need video.js in order to use videojs-markers.

Comment: yeah i did but the videojs-markers.min.js i cant find on a CDN.. and i only have access to the frontend of the site. When i literally copy all the videojs-markers.min.js code into the the page it still gives me the same error

Comment: @alecbaldwin Then I don't know if this will help, but here you go: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-markers/0.7.0/videojs-markers.js  Also, you can see a working example that I just used in another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60366511/1195615

Comment: ohhh yeeehhhssss it worked, ur awesome.. can replace my dodgy mutation observer code now haha